# ASP.NET MVC C# Multiple Url Routes Config Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, config

I want create route config multiple Url. ex: "fr-ca/user/login" and "en-ca/user/login" and its working, but if click submit and proccess data by controller and return RedirectToAction(MVC.User.Dashboard); always return "fr-ca/user/dashboard";
Although I use Url "en-ca/", and always return all link MVC.anything in first is "fr-ca/"

Because in position route config, "fr-ca" is first.

Maybe somebody can help me to solve this, thank u.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "fr-Default",
        url: "fr-ca/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = MVC.Content.Name, action = MVC.Content.ActionNames.Show, id = UrlParameter.Optional, siteId = Site.FR.Id },
         namespaces: new string[] { "Jay.Cms.Web.Controllers" }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "en-Default",
         url: "en-ca/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = MVC.Content.Name, action = MVC.Content.ActionNames.Show, id = UrlParameter.Optional, siteId = Site.EN.Id },
          namespaces: new string[] { "Jay.Cms.Web.Controllers" }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can write to action attribute in controller

'[Route("fr-ca/{controller}/{action}/{id}")]
 [Route("en-ca/{controller}/{action}/{id}")]
 public ActionResult Home()
 {
   return View();
 }'
```